# Is it possible to have table control in PropertyPane of Client Side Webpart with new SharePoint development framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I need to display a table inside the PropertyPane of Client side webpart with New SharePoint development framework.I can see we have property like Toggle, TextField, Button, ChoiceGroup,Dropdown etc under the PropertyPane-> PropertyPaneFields Folder. is it possible to have table control as well in property Pane.

Comment: not yet... there is no table as property in the new SPFx

Comment: I understand currently we dont have the Table Property, i would like to know, whether its possible by any other way

Comment: I dont know if it's possible to use React Table, you can give it a try  [React Table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#example)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can create your own control.  Check out this page here - https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls

There have been changes, so the documentation might be a bit out of date.

Answer (score 0):

yes, see https://github.com/russgove/spfxreactgrid for an example. you put a button in the property pane, that opens a pupup when clicked.